# Issues implementing double dispatch in C++

Tags: c++, oop, overloading

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I am trying to implement double dispatch in C++ but It doesn't seem to be taking. I suppose there may be something that I am missing? I don't believe object slicing is the issue as I am using pointers. I have read about issues with overload resolution and that double dispatch was a way around that. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code

```
class ReactType;
class ConditionerBase
  {
  public:
    ConditionerBase(/* args */){};
    ~ConditionerBase(){};
    virtual void visit(ReactType* reactor);
  };

  class ReactType
  {
  public:
    ReactType(/* args */){};
    ~ReactType(){};
    virtual void accept(ConditionerBase *conditioner);
  };
  
  class IdealReactType: public ReactType
  {
  public:
    IdealReactType(/* args */){};
    ~IdealReactType(){};
    virtual void accept(ConditionerBase *conditioner);
  };

  class Conditioner : public ConditionerBase
  {
  public:
    Conditioner(/* args */){};
    ~Conditioner(){};
    virtual void visit(ReactType* reactor){std::cout<<"Visited unknown reactor"<<std::endl;};
    virtual void visit(IdealReactType* ideal_reactor){std::cout<<"Visited ideal_reactor"<<std::endl;};
  };

  void ReactType::accept(ConditionerBase *conditioner){conditioner->visit(this);};
  void IdealReactType::accept(ConditionerBase *conditioner){conditioner->visit(this);};
  void ConditionerBase::visit(ReactType* reactor){std::cout<<"Base"<<std::endl;};

void doubleDispatchExample()
{

  std::vector<ReactType*> reactors;
  ReactType* unknown = new ReactType();
  IdealReactType* ideal_reactor = new IdealReactType();
  reactors.push_back(unknown);
  reactors.push_back(ideal_reactor);
  Conditioner conditioner;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    reactors.at(i)->accept(&conditioner);
  }
  delete unknown;
  delete ideal_reactor;
}
```

I want the output to be

```
Visited unknown reactor
Visited ideal reactor
```

but instead I get

```
Base
Base
```

when calling `doubleDispatchExample()`

It was suggested that I make the functions virtual which gives me

```
Visited unknown reactor
Visited unknown reactor
```

Comment: Make functions `visit` and `accept` virtual.

Comment: @Eugene making them virtual then gives me an output of `Visited unknown reactor Visited unknown reactor` which still isn't quite what I am looking for.

Comment: @Eugene, this comment lead me to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It greatly helps if you add `overload` on the functions which you expect to overload virtual functions.

Comment: Typo above. `override`, not `overload`. Take the advice. Can save oodles of debugging.

Comment: @user4581301 I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the `ConditionerBase` needs both classes of the overloaded functions and it gives me the desired output. Changing it to the following gives the output I want.

```
class ReactType;
class IdealReactType;
class ConditionerBase
  {
  public:
    ConditionerBase(/* args */){};
    ~ConditionerBase(){};
    virtual void visit(ReactType* reactor);
    virtual void visit(IdealReactType* reactor);
  };

  class ReactType
  {
  public:
    ReactType(/* args */){};
    ~ReactType(){};
    virtual void accept(ConditionerBase *conditioner);
  };
  
  class IdealReactType: public ReactType
  {
  public:
    IdealReactType(/* args */){};
    ~IdealReactType(){};
    virtual void accept(ConditionerBase *conditioner);
  };

  class Conditioner : public ConditionerBase
  {
  public:
    Conditioner(/* args */){};
    ~Conditioner(){};
    virtual void visit(ReactType* reactor){std::cout<<"Visited unknown reactor"<<std::endl;};
    virtual void visit(IdealReactType* ideal_reactor){std::cout<<"Visited ideal_reactor"<<std::endl;};
  };

  void ReactType::accept(ConditionerBase *conditioner){conditioner->visit(this);};
  void IdealReactType::accept(ConditionerBase *conditioner){conditioner->visit(this);};
  void ConditionerBase::visit(ReactType* reactor){std::cout<<"Base Reactor"<<std::endl;};
  void ConditionerBase::visit(IdealReactType* reactor){std::cout<<"Base Ideal"<<std::endl;};

void doubleDispatchExample()
{

  std::vector<ReactType*> reactors;
  ReactType* unknown = new ReactType();
  IdealReactType* ideal_reactor = new IdealReactType();
  reactors.push_back(unknown);
  reactors.push_back(ideal_reactor);
  Conditioner conditioner;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    reactors.at(i)->accept(&conditioner);
  }
  delete unknown;
  delete ideal_reactor;
}
```

Comment: Deriving from concrete class is usually a bad design. It is better to derive 2 concrete classes from a common abstract base.

Comment: Also, when you are tempted to use double dispatch for Visitor object-oriented pattern, consider the generic programming alternative provided by C++17 std library: `std::variant ` with `std::visit`.

Comment: @Eugene could you give an example of what deriving 2 concrete classes might look like. I am a bit confused how that would apply directly here.

Comment: @Eugene do you mean like make some functions purely virtual e.g. `virtual void visit(ReactType* reactor)=0;`?

Comment: Yes, "abstract base class" means a class with pure virtual functions. Concrete classes derive from it and override those functions. I am not saying base classes can never include non-pure functions, but implementing *all* functions in a base class and *instantiating* that base class is usually a bad idea.